# Equivalency of a matrix with prescribed singular values with a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Could anyone help me to solve this one?

Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix with elements $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$
Then I need to show the following:

A matrix $A$ has singular values  $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ iff $A$ is unitarily equivalent to $D$.

My definition for unitarily equivalent: Two matrix $M,N$ are said to be unitarily equivalent iff there exists unitary matrix $U,V$ such that $M=UNV$.

I tried like this:

Suppose $A$ has singular values $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$, 
$A$ has polar decomposition $A=UP$ where $U$ is unitary and $P$ is symmetric positive semidefinite,  and now  $P$ has eigenvalue decomposition $P=QDQ^*$ where $Q$ is unitary.

so $A=UQDQ^*=MDN$ where $M=UQ$ is unitary and $N=Q^*$ is unitary and hence $A$ is unitarily equivalent to $D$ some diagonal matrix.

But after this I am not able to proceed , please help

Comment: You're working too hard; this follows essentially immediately from the definition of the SVD, $A=U D V^*$, $U$ and $V^*$ are unitary, so $A$ is unitarily equivalent to $D$. The reverse direction works the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of a SVD of $A$ is $A=UDV^*$ where $U,V$ are unitary and $D=diag((\sigma_i)_i)$ is a non-negative diagonal matrix. Note that $U,V$ are not unique; yet $D$ is unique and the $(\sigma_i)$ are said the singular values of $A$ and the $(\sigma_i^2)_i$ are the eigenvalues of $AA^*$ or $A^*A$.